# My version SIM card won't work

Tags: server

My Verizon SIM card comes up unregistered and I'm wondering why my Ubuntu 4.5 Aquarius won't recognize the Verizon sim I am in the United States and I'm wondering why that it doesn't

Comment: I'm not an expert on how things are supposed to work on that side of the Atlantic, but [from the Verizon FAQ](http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/activate-4g-sim-card/) "A Verizon Wireless 4G SIM Card is a small 'smartcard' that is inserted into a Verizon Wireless-Certified 4G Device." Is the bq 4.5 certified by Verizon? If not, they might block it on other devices (I don't think that this is legal in Europe: my device, my connection, I do what I want with them)